# In My react native app i am not able to setState the ajax response

Tags: ajax, reactjs, react-native

```
constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {
     data: ''
  }
}


axios.post('/user', {
  firstName: 'Fred',
  lastName: 'Flintstone'
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
   this.setState({data: response });  // here i am getting error
   console.log(this.state.data);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

In My react native app i am not able to setState the ajax response.. When i am trying to update the state here it throws error and execute catch function... I don't know why it happens can you please give me the quick suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please read the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361380/5841629) between arrow functions and normal function declarations.

`this.setState({})` will only work if you use arrow functions `() =>` or you can do it the old fashion way by saving `this` inside a variable like so:

```
fetchData() {
    const self = this;
    axios.post('/user', {
      firstName: 'Fred',
      lastName: 'Flintstone'
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
       self.setState({data: response });  // here i am getting error
       console.log(self.state.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

I, however, prefer to use an arrow function instead as it's much simpler.

ex:

```
fetchData() {
    axios.post('/user', {
      firstName: 'Fred',
      lastName: 'Flintstone'
    })
    .then(response => this.setState({data: response }) )
    .catch(console.log);
}
```

P.S: You can also bind `this` using the `.bind(this)` method.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you use the ES2015 syntax to create your function, which doesn't bind the context by default.
Use an arrow function instead :

```
.then((reponse) => {
    console.log(response);
    this.setState({data: response });
    console.log(this.state.data);
}
```